# set a variable and log it

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I want to name a location and record this name in the access log.
I define a variable somewhere up in the config via a map and assign it an empty string as a value. Then, within locations I set appropriate values to it.
However, the access log displays empty strings.
What is the right way to do it?

The sequence of actions is as follows. The variable: $location_tag.

1. define
   `map "" $location_tag { default ""; }`
2. log
   `log_format: ... "$location_tag"`
3. set
   `location /x { ... set $location_tag "x"; }`

Step 1 is needed to avoid warnings of uninitialized values in the error log, since not all locations (there are tons of them) have this set directive.

Comment: I assume you named your log_format and referenced that name in an access_log statement. I have tested this and it works for me. Are you sure that the `location /x` is being selected to process the request?

Comment: Thank you for having tested it. Yes, the log format is properly named, it's a working one, I have just abbreviated it.  
It logs ok, and displays empty strings in quotes in place where the location tag must be.  
The locations are selected, I see the corresponding urls in the log.  
You say it works for you, which is baffling.  
Forgot to mention the nginx version: nginx/1.21.3 (nginx-plus-r25-p1).  
Ok, will keep on investigating, thanks again.